# Are you born detective?

Tags: mystery

I take facebook quiz, and here are some of the questions.

[image]

My answer is

> I choose the mother at the right. Because her hair is brown and child
>  hair is Black (I  think the father hair is black so the child hair is
>  black too). I may be wrong, because the mother at the left also can
>  have black hair husband too right?

[image]

My answer is

> I choose A, because the man is holding the child hand, the other
>  pictures the child is holding the man hand

These three I have no Idea.
[image]

[image]

[image]
Did my reasoning right? or are there better reasoning?

Comment: This puzzle is interestingly disturbing and disturbingly interesting!

Comment: The first one I also think is the woman on the right, for at least three reasons (yours seems to be too weak):
- she has a little belly, typical of women which has just given birth
- the child is playing at her feet (children prefers to play by giving their shoulders to the people they know)
- her hair is tied, typical of women with no so much time (because of their children, also)

Comment: For the first one, I think the mother is on the right too for these reasons : the child turn his back to her, meaning he trust her; the mother stay between her child and the exit so she can react if something happens like the other woman kidnap the child or the child try to run outside.

Comment: "Dissociative identity disorder criminals" is a weird turn of phrase. There [doesn't seem](https://bpded.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s40479-017-0053-9) to be much association between DID and criminality. This seems to be more about promoting (frankly rather stupid) stereotypes than anything else.

Comment: @NurnaniTati, clearly this is a thing you found somewhere else, and "facebook quiz" isn't quite what we consider proper attribution around here. Can you provide a link, or at least enough information for anyone who cares to find the original? (I say this reluctantly since to be honest I don't think the original deserves any extra traffic this might give it...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply guessing ..because seeing this type of puzzles first time ..

detective

> Center one , because that mustache is fake so it will be easy to stick it . And glass is big it cover is identity more.

serial killer

> first one king face , because it is easy to remove  just rubber band, since he is serial killer it does not for him to cover his identity.

weapon

> Baseball bat , as he has identity disorder may be he feels he is baseball player .

Comment: Maybe he has an identity disorder and thinks he is a knife-thrower. Maybe he has an identity disorder and thinks he is a treefeller.